# Modally Presenting a UINavigationController from UIPageViewController locks iOS 9

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, ios9, xcode7

So in my app we have a `UIPageViewController` that has a `UIToolbar` containing a button that when pressed instantiates a new `UINavigationController` and a `UIViewController` that is embedded in the nav controller. After this is completed I call `[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil]`. This spikes the CPU and locks up the app.

I set a breakpoint in the `UIViewController` that is embedded in the `UINavigationController` that is to be presented and the only call that ever executes is `initWithCoder:`.

This **ONLY** happens when using Xcode 7 and I have tried stripping it down to bare bones (not doing anything in the presented modal other than loading) but it doesn't help.

Comment: Click the "pause" button in the debugger and look at the stack trace to see what's being called once the CPU spikes.

Comment: It's just `obj_msgSend`

Comment: It seems to be stuck on `0x11376581c <+28>:  jmpq   *0x8(%r10)` and occasionally `[NSLocalizableString length]`, which I am not calling myself.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this is a new low for Apple in my opinion. The issue providing default text for a `UITextView`, but plain text, attributed text didn't cause the issue. That is almost embarrassing.

Comment: This is exactly what I encountered. If you have a UITextView on your modal you CANNOT overwrite the text via storyboard or else your modal will freeze your app. This is on Xcode 7 live on the App Store.